# Extending RegExp prototype without affecting the original behaviour

Tags: javascript, regex, object, prototype

I'm creating a lib that extends the RegExp.prototype with assign:

```
function VerExp() {
  return Object.assign(RegExp.prototype, {
    // my methods here
  });
}
```

But this is causing a weird behaviour when i try to use the compile function:

```
const regexp = new VerExp();
// some stuffs....
regexp.compile();
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Method RegExp.prototype.compile called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
```

But, if i create a new instance, extend it and return, will work:

```
function VerExp() {
  const regexp = new RegExp();
  return Object.assign(regexp, {
    // my methods here
  });
}

const regexp = new VerExp();
regexp.compile();
```

I would like to understand more the error, why is happening, how could i make it work extending the RegExp prototype, instead of the instance.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, MDN recommends not to use `RegExp.compile()`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/compile

Comment: What is purpose for extending `RegExp` prototype?

Comment: I'm adding new behaviours to the prototype object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `Object.assign` returns the same object the properties were assigned to.

```
Object.assign(RegExp.prototype, {
    // my methods here
});
```

will always return `RegExp.prototype`, so your function doesn't make much sense. All calls will reassign the same properties again and again, and return the same object.

Since [`RegExp.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-properties-of-the-regexp-prototype-object) is not a regex object, attempting to call regex methods on it will throw.

> The RegExp prototype object is an ordinary object. It is not a RegExp
>   instance and does not have a [[RegExpMatcher]] internal slot or any of
>   the other internal slots of RegExp instance objects.

What you probably want is subclass `RegExp`:

```js
class VerExp extends RegExp {
  // my methods here
}
const regexp = new VerExp();
regexp.compile();
console.log("No error");
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you Oriol.